# SDC constraints at the module level

Tags: fpga, quartus, sdc

Must be simple question I can't find answer for.

I design Synposys design constraints file, and have a module, let's call it module1. A the top I connect it using

```
module1 module1 (
...
);
```

and then want separate SDC file for this module1. I put it into the directory the module source is, but Quartus wants absolute path names, e.g.

```
module1:module1|register
```

And of course if I change module name to something else whole SDC file becomes invalid. Is there any way to tell Quartus to use SDC file at the level of the module1 only and work only in this module's scope? E.g.

```
module1|register
```

and wherever I connect the module to the SDC will be used at the level of this connected module.